# Rails 6: Can I have assets prefix for Webpacker files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I' working with Rails 6.0.1. My final target is to have all urls in my app starting with `/xyz/`.

In Rails 5, I could set

```
config.assets.prefix = "/xyz/assets"
```

and JavaScript files would be served as `/xyz/assets/application.js` etc.

Now with Rails 6 (default setup using Webpacker), JavaScript urls would look like

```
/packs/js/application.js
```

Is there a way to serve JavaScript files from

```
/xyz/packs/js/application.js
```

instead?

Answer (score 2):

In `config/webpacker.yml` set the base path with `public_output_path`:

```
default: &default
  public_output_path: packs
```